# JButton change of icon using Mouse Listeners

Tags: button, icons, mouseevent, mouselistener, mouseclick-event

I want to create an effect on JButtons so that they change their icons on cursor hover and when being clicked, and also restore them on click end/cursor out. 
I created 3 mouse listeners that change the buttons' icons when the mouse is clicked, entered and exited. The problem is when the button is pressed it changes it's icon and then when I take the cursor outside the button, the `mouseExcited` function goes in and thus I cannot change it permanently. I guess I should write some kind of an ,,if pressed" statement but I have no idea how and where.

```
p.star.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource());
        ImageIcon starIcon = new ImageIcon("star.png");
        p.star.setIcon(starIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
       ImageIcon starIcon = new ImageIcon("star.png");
       p.star.setIcon(starIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        ImageIcon starIcon = new ImageIcon("star_blue.png");
        p.star.setIcon(starIcon);
    }

    });
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help :)

Comment: hi, I've fixed code formatting a bit, and now I can see some extra closing brackets that don't match any opening ones, could you fix those in a way they are in your code? I've also changed the terms in the first sentence to somewhat more conventional ones, so you may want to update the rest of your text

Comment: Thank you :) Sure, I will change it!